# Jquery Autocomplete from Table

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am new and struggling to find a way to create a searchable dropdownlist (MVC5/C#).  I have tried Select2, and could not get it working.  I am desperate and out of time.

Looking at a few tutorials on Jquery Autocomplete, it seems pretty straight and forward.  My problem is that all of the examples on line seems to use static data.  My dropdownlist is populated from my Controller using a List of pre-filtered results.

This is how I populate my doprdownlist

```
List<SelectListItem> autocomplete = db.ICS_Supplies.Where(s => s.InvType == "F").Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Supplies_ID.ToString(), Text = x.Old_ItemID + "  " + "  |  " + "  " + " Description:  " + x.ItemDescription, Selected = false }).DistinctBy(p => p.Text).OrderBy(p => p.Text).ToList();
ViewBag.FormsList = new SelectList(autocomplete, "Value", "Text");
```

As is, the dropdown populates - but it has a lot of records and is VERY slow.

From most of the examples I have seen online, the searchable items are something like:

```
var options = [
{ value: 'Adam', data: 'AD' },
 // ...
{ value: 'Tim', data: 'TM' }
];
```

That's great, if I want to type out a thousand possible items - but I need to populate my DropDownList options from a table.  .. and I am lost.

I am very new to Jquery and any direction is greatly appreciated.

EDIT1*

I am adding the View Code (from the online Example) for more clarification

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
<label for="files">Select Supply:</label>
<input type="text" name="supplies" id="autocomplete" />
</div>
<div>
Selected Option : <span class="label label-default" id="selected_option"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-Autocomplete-using-Web-Service-in-ASP.Net.aspx it might help

Comment: @casenonsensitive - thank you for that.  I will walk through that and see if it helps.

Comment: The trick to dynamically generating an autocomplete list is to use ajax, but you need to be querying a page close by to get good response times - over the web is slow. I'll post some js code in an answer to get you started - you'll have to adapt this to your needs. It's the definition of a jQuery implementation that uses ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need ajax to get a dynamic autocomplete list. Here's some sample code - it's the definition of a basic jQuery implementation that uses ajax.

```
function close_autocomplete($elemid) {
    jQuery($elemid).autocomplete("destroy" );
}

function attach_autocomplete($elemid) {
    jQuery($elemid)
        .autocomplete({
            delay : 250,
            minLength : 3,
            source  :   function( request, response ) { 
                            var $thedata = request.term;
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url : myajaxresponder.php,
                                type : "GET",
                                data : {  
                                        action_id : "autocomplete",
                                        thedata : $thedata
                                },
                                error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                    console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                                    response("");
                                },
                                success : function (result) {
                                    var resultarray = JSON.parse(result);
                                    response(resultarray);
                                }
                            });
                        },
            select  :   function ( event, ui ) {
                            jQuery($elemid).val(ui.item.value);
                            return false;
                        },               

        })
}

// attach the handlers
    jQuery("#myid").focus(function ()
                         {attach_autocomplete(jQuery(this).prop("id"))});
    jQuery("#myid").blur(function () 
                          {close_autocomplete(jQuery(this).prop("id"))});
```